# Logic - An application of combining first-order logic statements

Tags: first-order-logic

Consider the sets $\Omega_b$ and $B_a$ which are dependent on $b$ and $a$, respectively and the function $ x:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow D $. There are three propositions:
$$
\begin{align}
&P_1 : \forall a > 0: \exists b>0 : \Omega_b \subseteq B_a\\
&P_2 : \forall b > 0: \exists T > 0 : \forall t > T : x(t) \in \Omega_b\\
&P_3 : \forall a > 0: \exists T > 0 : \forall t > T : x(t) \in B_a
\end{align}
$$

I want to show that $P_1$ and $P_2$ imply $P_3$ in formula form,  that is, $P_1 \land P_2 \Rightarrow P_3$. I believe it is true but I can't figure out how to rigorously show that.

What I tried:

From $P_1$ and axiom of choice, it is guaranteed that a choice function $c:\mathbb{R}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $\Omega_{c(a)} \subseteq B_a$ exists.

From $P_2$ together with $P_1$, we have $\forall a > 0: \exists T > 0 : \forall t > T : x(t) \in \Omega_{c(a)} \subseteq B_a$.

Comment: How is this related to stability theory?

Comment: @NoahSchweber It is obviously not related to stability theory directly. But it is a part of the proof of Lyapunov direct method. I removed the tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$
$\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace{#1}}$

I spent some time learning the Fitch-style system and tried applying it to my problem. The proposition seemed intuitively true, but I didn't know how to formally and unambiguously prove it.

$$
 \fitch{
  1.~\forall a > 0: \exists b>0 : \Omega_{b} \subseteq B_{a}\\
  2.~\forall b > 0: \exists T > 0 : \forall t > T : x(t) \in \Omega_{b}
 }{
  \fitch{3.~\boxed{a_{1}}~a_{1}>0}{
   4.~\exists b>0:\Omega_{b} \subseteq B_{a_{1}}~\tab[4cm]\forall\text{-Elim: 1}\\
   \fitch{5.~\boxed{b_{1}}~b_{1}>0 \land \Omega_{b_{1}}\subseteq B_{a_{1}}}{
    6.~\exists T > 0 : \forall t > T : x(t) \in \Omega_{b_{1}} \subseteq B_{a_{1}}~\tab[1cm]\forall\text{-Elim: 2}
   }\\
  7.~\exists T > 0 : \forall t > T : x(t) \in B_{a_{1}}~\tab[2cm]\exists\text{-Elim: 4, 5-6}
  }\\
 8.~\forall a > 0: \exists T > 0 : \forall t > T : x(t) \in B_{a}~\tab[1cm]\forall\text{-Intro: 3-7}
 }
$$